# How to selet spreadsheet one after another in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

How to select spreadsheets one after another in Google Apps Script to perform some action in them?

In excel vba the following code worked, but it does not work in Google Apps Script

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For Each ws in wb.Worksheets

        'Do something here
    End if
Next
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You get the active spreadsheet (workbook) with [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)
- You get the list of sheets (worksheets) in your spreadsheet with [Spreadsheet.getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()).
- There are many ways to iterate through the sheets. For example, with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();  
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    // Do something
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- I strongly recommend taking a look at Apps Script guides. There's a good list of links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info), where you can start learning.